# How to get the width of the ligature using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

How to get the width of the ligature? Suppose I have a ligature ff can I get the exact width of it?
When I do this:

```
doc.setProperty(Property.TYPOGRAPHY_CONFIG, new TypographyConfigurator()
        .addFeatureConfig(
            new StandardScriptConfig(new HashSet<Character.UnicodeScript>(Arrays.asList(Character.UnicodeScript.LATIN, Character.UnicodeScript.CYRILLIC)))
                    .setLigaturesApplying(true)
        ));
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
font.getWidth("ff", 13);
```

That gives the usual width ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Getting width of "ﬀ" ligature specifically

The ligature in question has its own designated Unicode character `U+FB00`, so to get its with you can use.

```
font.getWidth("\uFB00", 12);
```

### Getting width of arbitrary text string processed by pdfCalligraph

By specifying `Property.TYPOGRAPHY_CONFIG` you implicitly use `pdfCalligraph` module which is responsible for applying calligraphic features like ligatures. This is a closed-source add-on which does not have public API to interact with and is intended to seamlessly integrate into existing code.

To get the effective with (as it would be displayed in the resultant PDF) of any layout element, you can manually layout such an element and then get some of the properties of the layout result, such as the calculated width.

You can have a method like following to calculate width of the text:

```
float calculateTextWidth(Document document, String text) throws IOException {
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text).setFont(font);
    IRenderer paragraphRenderer = p.createRendererSubTree();
    paragraphRenderer.setParent(document.getRenderer()).layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, new Rectangle(100, 100))));
    return paragraphRenderer.getChildRenderers().get(0).getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getWidth();
}
```

Make sure the rectangle you are passing to the `LayoutArea` constructor is large enough to fit all the text (100x100 in our case is more than enough).

Then if you try to compare the output of the method before setting `Property.TYPOGRAPHY_CONFIG` and after that, you will most likely see different values provided that the font contains the ligature. In my case those values were `9.984` and `9.768`, respectively. As you are interested in the width of the ligature, make sure to call this method after applying the typography configuration to the document.

Comment: While this is surely correct, it looks like a huge hassle for getting the exact width of a ligature...

Comment: @mkl well, for the very specific ligature in question there is of course a faster way of retrieving its width - I've updated my answer. In the generic case I think the way I suggested if more than okay as it allows to deal with any transformations pdfCalligraph does. Because it's closed source separate modules we cannot get the same result using only iText Core, and if we start making exceptions for ligatures only, who knows where we end up in the end.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which pairs of letters are ligatures? Just if thousands of letters are checked using the method you described earlier, it will take a lot of time! (На русском: А есть способ узнать, какие именно пары букв являются лигатурами?Просто если тысячи букв проверять методом который вы описали раньше, это займет много времени

Comment: @crazy_deviL I don't think there is a good way that I can recommend of finding all combinations that form a ligature out of the box. But I think if you put all your combinations (even thousands of them) into one paragraph and separate them with newlines, then using adaptation of my suggestion shouldn't be very time-consuming. iText is capable of creating large documents quickly, so creating virtual documents of ~100 pages at most shouldn't be a problem. Of course if you don't do it too often :)